# Maintaining the first height an element has as the content inside it changes

Tags: jquery, html, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I currently have an image gallery where there's an image in full size to the left and all the other images from the gallery to the left like so:

```
<div class='col-md-7'>
    <img src='something'>
</div>
<div class='col-md-5'>
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat for all the images in the array>
            <img thumbnail for the image, on click it changes the source of the main image>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Problem is, images can have different heights and as the img height changes so does the main container and the height of each thumbnail (since they're responsive to the parent size). Is there a way to determine the initial height for the gallery and keep it that way as the user changes images? I don't want to set a static numeric value since it's supposed to scale with screen size and because there can be multiple galleries in the same page I need each one to remember its own height.

As you can see in the example I'm using bootstrap and angularJS as well as jQuery, so tools available to those frameworks are available.

Answer (score 0):

Get the initial `offsetHeight` of all your `img` elements you don't want the height to change and set its `height` to the value you get.

In the below snippet, the line doing that is:

```
img.style.height = img.offsetHeight + "px";
```

```js
let gallery = [
  'https://picsum.photos/200/100/?image=1080',
  'https://picsum.photos/200/200/?image=1063',
  'https://picsum.photos/500/200/?image=1060',
  'https://picsum.photos/300/300/?image=1059',
  'https://picsum.photos/200/300/?image=1070',
  'https://picsum.photos/300/200/?image=1071'
];

let thumbs = document.getElementById("thumbnails");

for (let i = 1; i < gallery.length; i++) {
  thumbs.appendChild(thumbs.firstElementChild.cloneNode(true));
}

let img = document.querySelector(".col-md-7").firstElementChild;

gallery.forEach((url, i) => {
  thumbs.children[i].firstChild.src = url;
});

thumbs.addEventListener("click", event => {
  if (event.target.tagName === "IMG") {
    img.src = event.target.src;
  }
});

img.src = gallery[0];
img.style.height = img.offsetHeight + "px";
// The above last line is the code keeping the initial height.
```

```css
#thumbnails {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
}

#thumbnails li {
  float: left;
  height: 35px;
  width: 50px;
  margin: 10px;
  background: #fde;
}

#thumbnails img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class='col-md-7'>
    <img>
</div>
<div class='col-md-5'>
    <ul id="thumbnails">
      <li><img></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**EDIT:** *(to answer comment)*

From what I understand so far, you can do something like this:

**HTML**

Each gallery has been wrapped in a `<div class="gallery"></div>`. Thumbnail image sources are added by `ng-repeat`

```
<div class="gallery">
  <div class='col-md-7'>
    <img src='something'>
  </div>

  <div class='col-md-5'>
    <ul class="thumbnails">
      <li ng-repeat="some-token">
        <img src="{{img.src}}"> 
               <!-- img.src here represents the url from each
                    iteration in your data -->
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="gallery">
  <div class='col-md-7'>
    <img src='something'>
  </div>

  <div class='col-md-5'>
    <ul class="thumbnails">
      <li ng-repeat="some-token">
        <img src="{{img.src}}">
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

The code runs for each gallery in the `galleries` collection, so each gallery has its own scope.

```
let galleries = document.getElementsByClassName("gallery");

[].forEach.call(galleries, gallery => {
  let image = gallery.querySelector("img");
  image.style.height = image.offsetHeight + "px"; // Initial height

  let thumbs = gallery.querySelector(".thumbnails");
  thumbs.addEventListener("click", event => {
    if (event.target.tagName === "IMG") {
      image.src = event.target.src;
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: How would I adapt this to run after each element is created by an ng-repeat? Basically what I have is a set of galleries created by an ng-repeat

Comment: Apologies for the late response. After tinkering with the CSS some more I noticed that I could get rid of the problem by removing the `max-height` property I was setting on the `ul`, so far nothing seems to have broken.